How to hit Klavio API in android using Retrofit HTTP Call in android
POST METHOD
URL : https://a.klaviyo.com/api/profile-subscription-bulk-create-jobs/
This is my Post request method :
Header : revision:2024-07-15
content-type:application/json
accept:application/json
Authorization:Klaviyo-API-Key android89459832432sdskjha
request body raw type :

{"data":{"type":"profile-subscription-bulk-create-job","attributes":{"profiles":{"data":[{"type":"profile","attributes":{"email":"anilkt87@gmail.com"}}]}},"relationships":{"list":{"data":{"type":"list","id":"YXOSus"}}}}}

when i try to hit above request from Postman i am able to get response 200.
when i try to execute same code using Retrofit in Android using below code :
 public void createSubscription() {
        klaviyoService = KalvioRetrofitClient.getKlaviyoService();
        String data = "{\"data\":{\"type\":\"profile-subscription-bulk-create-job\",\"attributes\":{\"profiles\":{\"data\":[{\"type\":\"profile\",\"attributes\":{\"email\":\"anilkt87@gmail.com\"}}]}},\"relationships\":{\"list\":{\"data\":{\"type\":\"list\",\"id\":\"YXOSus\"}}}}}";
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        Call<Response<String>> call = klaviyoService.createSubscription(jsonObject);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Response<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d("Klaviyo", "Subscription status: " + response);
                } else {
                    Log.e("Klaviyo", "Failed to create subscription: " + response.errorBody());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Response<String>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("Klaviyo", "Error creating subscription", t);
            }
        });
    }


public class KalvioRetrofitClient {
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
    public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            // Set up logging interceptor (optional, for debugging)
            HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                        @NonNull
                        @Override
                        public Response intercept(@NonNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
                            Request request = chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                                    .addHeader("accept", "application/json").addHeader("revision", "2024-07-15").addHeader("Authorization", "Klaviyo-API-Key android89459832432sdskjha").build();
                            return chain.proceed(request);
                        }
                    })
                    .build();

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }

    public static KlaviyoService getKlaviyoService() {
        return getClient("https://a.klaviyo.com/").create(KlaviyoService.class);
    }
}


public interface KlaviyoService {
    @POST("api/profile-subscription-bulk-create-jobs")
    Call<Response<String>> createSubscription(@Body JSONObject klaviyoRequest);

}

I am getting Error 400 with error. Failed to create subscription: okhttp3.ResponseBody$Companion$asResponseBody$1@a3bd973
I don't know why this error is coming while i have given correct key and list id same thing is working fine in post man but not  using retrofit call .
can any one help me in this  what wrong i am doing .
Thanks
